# which sql supports vista

Tags: sql

i have windows vista in my laptop..
i have installed visual studio 2008..i need sql server...
i tried sqlexpress 2005.. it shows the compatibility issues.. i proceeded further, finally it shows error 1603.. i provided full rights to the directory where installed..
help me..

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SQLServer Express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/) which is the latest version. It works fine for me on **WinV**.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both SQL Express2005 and 2008 on vista with no problems. I think 2005 did show a compatibility warning when I installed it but it ran fine. I would try SQL Express 2008 just because its the latest version.

If you continue to get errors installing then I would check you have the latest windows service packs installed.

I've had a quick look at what could cause error 1603 and found this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916760 . It sounds like it could be a bad installer, try downloading the installer again and see if you get the same problem. Also if your trying to install it from a network drive try copying the installer to your local PC and running it form there.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/) is free and has no problems with vista